# Is there an expected race condition when recreating a deleted LoadBalancer Service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-service

We've noticed a race condition when performing the following actions (on Azure Kubernetes Services):

0. install a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` (via a Helm chart, using `helm install`)
1. delete the `Service` (using `helm uninstall`)
2. recreate the `Service` (using `helm install` again)

As the Service has a [finalizer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#garbage-collecting-load-balancers), the Service will not really be deleted when the API server returns from step 1. Instead, it will only be marked for deletion. Therefore, if executed fast enough, step 2 will not recreate anything and in the end, there will be no `Service` even though the Helm chart seems to be installed.

I wonder if this is expected or if I should raise a bug report with Kubernetes (because, e.g., the API server should refuse to modify a service currently being deleted) or Helm (because, e.g., they should notice that the resource is currently deleted and therefore cannot be reinstalled).

Comment: That sequence makes total sense to me as you've described it.  Filing a bug report would still make sense (probably against Helm).  I've run into some similar issues deleting and reinstalling things in a script, FWIW.

Comment: @DavidMaze Would you like to post your comment as a response so I can choose it as an answer?